# Getting docker-compose to build container that uses a parent container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a setup that I am migrating to docker-compose from a set of shell scripts. The container I want to build uses a parent container that is created by a custom dockerfile. But I can't see how to get docker-compose to (re)build the requisite parent container.

There are three files as per:

/code/containers/parent/DockerFile

```
FROM centos:7  
RUN... (rest of file to create common stuff used by multiple child images)
```

/code/containers/child-one/Dockerfile

```
FROM parent
RUN...
```

/code/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  my-service:
    image: child-one
    build:
      dockerfile: containers/child-one/Dockerfile
      context: .
```

As expected it will fail with:
Service 'my-service' failed to build: repository parent not found: does not exist or no pull access

Can't find any solution to this other than manually running docker to build the parent image first.

Any ideas much appreciated.

edit: base on VonCs idea:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  parent-notservice;
    image: parent
    build:
      dockerfile: containers/parent/Dockerfile
      context: .

  my-service:
    image: child-one
    depends_on:
      parent
    build:
      dockerfile: containers/child-one/Dockerfile
      context: .
```

However I had to use depends_on, which was a hack, I am worried about effects of the parent starting (when child is run). This is not my intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"parent" would exist in your local docker registry if your build was setting the name "parent" (`docker build -t parent`)

With a docker-compose file, you need to build `parent/DockerFile` first, with an `image: parent` under your [**`build`** directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

However, you should only build service you intent to *run*, which is not the case for "parent": parent should be built *before* docker-compose is involved.
The proper solution is to have a wrapper script which would:

- `docker build -t parent ...`
- then call `docker-compose`

No more `depends_on` hack between imaginary services (there is no "service" for `parent`: nothing runs there).

Comment: Cheers VonC,
Based on that I know have:
  
    version: '3.3'  
    services:
      parent-notservice;
        image: parent
        build:
          dockerfile: containers/parent/Dockerfile
          context: .

      my-service:
        image: child-one
        depends_on:
          parent
        build:
          dockerfile: containers/child-one/Dockerfile
          context: .
      

However the use of depends_on was a hack, I am worried about parent starting when child is run.

Comment: @Duckman Actually, I have amended my answer to propose another approach.

Answer (score 6):

As of January 2021, there is another way to do this by using the `profiles` key. Support for this key was added in Docker Compose 1.28.0.

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  parent-notservice:
    build:
      dockerfile: containers/parent/Dockerfile
      context: .
    profiles:
      - donotstart

  my-service:
    image: parent-notservice

  another-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./containers/service/Dockerfile
```

`my-service` will be based directly on `parent-notservice.` Then you can add whatever `ports` and `volumes` are needed for that container in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

`another-service` will be built from the Dockerfile which could also be based on `parent-notservice` using the `FROM` command. Other packages can then be installed on that container that are not part of the parent.

```
FROM parent-notservice
RUN...
```

And the best part is that when you use `docker-compose up` the `parent-notservice` will not start.

Further documentation on the `profiles` key can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Comment: This is true, but to stay with you example the parent-notservice container image in the local docker repository is prefixed with the project name or folder name of Dockerfile, so for I had to use `FROM docker-parent-notservice` in the childs Dockerfile.